# CodeIgniter menu with subitems from a single DB table

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, dynamic, menu

Just getting into the whole MVC developing style.

Using CI I think I got the initial hang on the controllers, models and views. But, I run into a problem which was an easy-peasy for me in "my own" way of coding.

I have a single DB table to drive dynamic menu. The design is:

[image: DB design]

With sample data being:

[image: DB sample data]

The logic, in my head anyway, would be:

1. select * where active=1, then
2. if row's **parent_id==0** check the retrieved data-set for rows where
   **parent_id==id** of the current row
3. if not found, generate `<li class="no_subs"></li>` element
4. if found, generate `<li class="subs">` element, open new `<ul>`
5. generate `<li></li>` for all items that matched, close `<ul>`, close
   "subs" `<li>`

So, based on the above sample data the resulting html would be:

```
<li class="no_subs">Home</li>
<li class="no_subs">News</li>
<li class="subs">Training
      <ul>
         <li>Materials</li>
         <li>Tests</li>
     </ul>
</li>
<li class="subs">Other
      <ul>
         <li>Usefull links</li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

So far all I can do is generate the top level menu.
Any ideas how to tackle this?

Thanks,

Comment: I would personally pass the query data into a menu class of some sort with a public method to test if a menu item hasChildren(). This is easier than you think, but I don't have the time to write out a bunch of classes and examples sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table twice to achieve your goal

1. grub the data where `parent_id == 0` and `active == 1`, so you will get the only menu titles.
2. join the data with the same table where `id == parent_id`. so you will get the this table.

id | name | parent_id | active | link | as_id | as_name | as_parent_id | as_active | as_link

**this 2 steps can be done in single sql query.

then i think this code will help you...

```
       $sub_menu_started = false;
        for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { 
            if (empty($result[$i]['as_name'])) {
                echo '<li class="no_subs">'.$result[$i]['name'].'</li>';
            }
            else {
                if(!$sub_menu_started) {
                    echo '<li class="subs">'.$result[$i]['name'];
                    echo '<ul><li>'.$result[$i]['as_name'].'</li>';
                    $sub_menu_started = true;
                }
                else {
                    if ($result[$i]['id'] == $result[$i-1]['id']) {
                        echo '<li>'.$result[$i]['as_name'].'</li>';
                        if($result[$i]['id'] != $result[$i+1]['id']) {
                            echo '</ul></li>';
                            $sub_menu_started = false;
                        }
                    }                       
                }   
            }
        }
        if ($sub_menu_started) {
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
```